# what MS options are available for a student interested in computer vision and image processing?

Tags: masters, computer-science, professorship, electrical-engineering

I have my bachelors in electronics and instrumentation and a research experience in the field of image processing and computer vision and some publications in the same.Can i go for a MS in computer science, robotics or signal processing. Also tell me some other Ms options available for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55858/22733) twice.