# What are the masters options available for getting into computer vision and image processing research from an electronics background?

Tags: computer-science, changing-fields, electrical-engineering

Having done bachelors in electronics and instrumentation and a research experience in the field of image processing and computer vision and some publications in the same, what are the possible MS options where I can study computer vision and image processing? Can I opt for MS in robotics, computer science, signal processing?

My confusion is regarding the fact that I was a bachelors student in a different field. Would it be difficult for me to change to a masters program in this other field?

Answer (score 1):

There are Masters of Science programs in Computer Visions and even Computer Science that you can definitely look into. I'm not sure if your preference is to attend school online or on campus. I'm not sure of your location or budget either, so this answer will sound quite generic. However, I have included Georiga Tech's program. The Georgia Tech link is just a course in Computer Visions that's part of their Master of Science in Computer Science program. I believe their program is $7,000 (if it hadn't increased) and it's fully online. I've included their online Masters site link.

[Georgia Tech](https://www.class-central.com/mooc/1022/georgia-tech-online-master-of-science-in-computer-science-cs-4495-computer-vision)
[Georiga Tech Online Masters](http://www.omscs.gatech.edu/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am basically interested in an on campus program. But my confusion is regard the fact that can I go in these field despite of being a bachelors student in a different field. would it be difficult for me?.

Comment: I believe you can do it. A bachelors in electronics can simply tie into computer science. I'm answering this based on the general idea of an electronics degree, without seeing the specific courses that you've already taken. Your research experience will definitely help you alot. Also, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Every research option that is available can be researched in any level from bachelors to doctorate. Masters in no exception here. Only the amount of effort you put into it differs.